# Spring Webflux cpu in a container environment

Tags: spring, kubernetes, containers, cpu, webflux

In our environment with kubernetes, our pods usually have less than 1 cpu core reserved.
Knowing that spring webflux works with the concept of eventloop + workers,
how would that work? is it recommended that we reserve at least 1 cpu core for this pod?

If i still use webflux with less than 1cpu request in kubernetes, will my eventloop be underperformance?